# MySql get number of customer who has placed more then 3 orders

Tags: mysql, join, count

I have a customer table and a order table i want to count how many active customers have made more then 3 orders the structure of the tables is like this:

```
Customer table

customer_id, name, active

orders table

order_id, details, customer_id
```

Any help?

Comment: try with group by and having. If not sure how to do, please read about it in google

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
SELECT c.customer_id,
       c.name
  FROM Customer AS c
  INNER JOIN orders as o
     ON o.customer_id = c.customer_id
  WHERE c.active
  GROUP BY c.customer_id,
           c.name
  HAVING COUNT(c.customer_id) > 3
```

Comment: thanks i figured it out other day tho what bout if i used case statement would that make it faster